# How to fill bidimensional arrays in fortran90

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, montecarlo

i have an issue about filling a bidimensional array in Fortran90. in my program I extract different sets of random numbers and check them as uncertainties to my measurements ustar and Tstar, and i get uerr and terr. Now I want to put uerr and terr in a two-dimensional array because then I have to repeat this procedure n times to get different dataset (the Monte Carlo method for the estimation of errors). How do I assign uerr and terr to my array? And how do I iterate the process n times each time you run the program? I tried giving my array "set" the indexes r and c but at compile I get:

```
Warning: Extension: REAL array index at (1)
```

i read ustar and tstar from an input file, the code is below:

```
program stimerr
 implicit none

 character(len=12) filein,fileout
 integer,dimension(1) :: seed = (/4/)
 real, dimension(2) :: num
 integer :: n,h,i
 real, dimension(24,2) :: set 
 real :: pi = 3.14159
 real :: g1,g2,ustar,tstar,uerr,terr

 write(*,'(2x,''File di input .......''/)')
 read(*,'(a12)') filein
 open(unit=120,File=filein)

 set = 0.

 call init_random_seed ()
  do n=1,24
  read(120,*) h,ustar,tstar
  call random_number(num)

  g1 =(sqrt(-2*log(num(1)))*(cos(2*pi*(num(2)))))/10.
  g2 =(sqrt(-2*log(num(1)))*(sin(2*pi*(num(2)))))/10.

  uerr = ustar + g1
  terr = tstar + g2

  write(*,*) set(uerr,terr)


  enddo


close(120)



end program stimerr
```

Comment: The error seems self explanatory, you are trying to use real variables as array indices. the indices to `set` should be like `set(n,1)` , `set(n,2)`.   You never assign anything to set before you try to write it by the way. Very unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: While I agree with the general thrust of your comment @agentp the line `set = 0.` does assign a value to the elements of `set`.

Comment: oh thanks, i corrected those lines with
   set(n,:) = uerr
   set(:,n) = terr
and ask to write the array "set" but now it prints 24 times the same values for every loop. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use the `fortran` tag if you want to get more attention. Use `fortran90` in addition if you have something specific to this version what cannot be found in later ones or some other particularity.